# I am getting an error :0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported PWA

Tags: magento2, progressive-web-apps, magento2.4, venia

I am getting an error when I run the below command

yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept

```
  ⓧ  error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
  ⓧ  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

```
PHP     : 8.1
Magento : 2.4.4
Node    : v17.8.0
NPM     : 8.5.5
```

Comment: That's likely due to using v17, any particolar reason you're not going for the 16LTS which should work fine atm?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding below to you pwa installation

In Linux or Mac

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Or In windows

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```